# Gerrit: Hotkey for adding a reply

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gerrit

I've started using Gerrit recently. I see that there are shortcut keys for almost anything, but I don't see a shortcut for the "Reply..." button. Is there one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `a` key

> a :   Review and publish comments

It is written at the last of shortcut list available by pressing `?` key on review page.

*Tested OK in version 2.12.2*